# Define a function that creates text file with strings from two other text files in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I have another question. I thought I understood what I was doing in this task, but apparently not. We are given two TXT-files, and we are supposed to define a function that takes three arguments, all of them being TXT-files. The first file looks thus:

> hello
>   
>  thank you (etc.)

and the second file:

> hola
>   
>  gracias (etc.)

We are supposed to define the function so that these two files are composed into a new file like so:

> hello:hola
>   
>  thank you:gracias (etc.)

Where the number of items in the first and second file are not the same, we are supposed to break the function and return an error. That part seems to work fine, and my programme also creates a new TXT-file, but it's always empty. See for yourself:

```
def create_dictionary(file1, file2, newfile):
    with open(file1, encoding='utf-8') as fobj_1:
        with open(file2, encoding='utf-8') as fobj_2:
            a = fobj_1.readlines()
            b = fobj_2.readlines()
            if len(a) != len(b):
                return "The input files are not compatible."
            else:
                with open(newfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fobj_new:
                    for line1 in fobj_1:
                        out1 = line1.rstrip()
                        for line2 in fobj_2:
                            out2 = line2.rstrip()
                        fobj_new.write(out1 + ":" + out2 + "\n")
                return "Successfully created file."
```

The programme runs fine for two files that don't match, but the "else:" condition creates an empty file. What very obvious thing am I missing here?

Comment: You've already iterated over the files with readlines, so the cursor's at the end of the file. Use a and b instead of fobj_1 and fobj_2. Note that this will show you a *different* problem with your code, but keep solving them until there aren't any left!

Answer (score 0):

Looping over the input files exhausts their data. Trying to `read` again requires you to rewind, or close and reopen the files. But you already have the data in memory, in the variables `a` and `b`; loop over them.

```py
for ind in len(a):
    first = a[ind].strip()
    second = b[ind].strip()
    out1.write(f'{first}:{second}\n')
```

Notice also how there is a single loop; your attempt would write the first element in `a` followed by each of the elements in `b` in turn, then the second element in `a` followed by each element from `b`, etc.